# Adding Parameters to Command Vs Adapter

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, ado.net

I'm curious if there is a difference, if any between adding Parameters to the `OracleCommand` and then adding them to the `OracleDataAdapter` or by directly adding them to the `OracleDataAdapter`?

For example,

Adding them to the `OracleCommand` and then linking them to the `OracleDataAdpater`

```
string f= "foo";
string sql = "SELECT @c FROM Dual";

using(OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(sql, this.Connection))
{
    OracleParameter param = new OracleParameter("@c", f);
    command.Parameters.Add(param);
    OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
    adapter.SelectCommand = command;
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(dataset);
    return dataset;
}
```

Adding them directly to the `OracleDataAdapter`

```
string f= "foo";
string sql = "SELECT @c CalcVarValue FROM Dual";
using(OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(sql, this.Connection))
{
    OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@c", f));
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(dataset);
    return dataset;
}
```

Is one way more preferred over the other? Is adding to the `OracleDataAdapter` directly faster in execution compared to the other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference whatsoever. In both cases, the parameter is added to the `OracleCommand`.

Choosing between these two coding styles is a matter of personal preference, coding conventions you are obligated to (if exists) and mostly, opinion.

Personally, I tend to go with the shortest possible code that you can still read a year from the day you wrote it and understand what it does without having to think about it, or as someone once wrote (I think it was on Meta.SE) - In this industry, you should write your code as simple as possible, because the person that will take over the project after you will most likely be an idiot.